# React Native: display Firestore boolean value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to display a Firestore boolean value on my application. Below is my code.

```
const SubmitVote =() => {
  const [voteLists, setvoteLists] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [nric, setNric ] = useState('');
  const [state, setState ] = useState('');
  const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');

  const [barisan, setBarisan] = useState('');
  const [pkr, setPkr] = useState('');
  const [dap, setDap] = useState('');
  const [pas, setPas] = useState('');

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(()=>{
    db.collection('PARLIMEN').get().then(snapShot=>{
      snapShot.forEach((snap)=>{
        setName(snap.data().name);
        setNric(snap.data().nric);
        setBarisan(snap.data().barisan);
        setPkr(snap.data().pkr);
        setDap(snap.data().dap);
        setPas(snap.data().pas);
      })
    })         
  },[]);

return(
  <View>
    <View  style={{padding:20}} >
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{name}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{nric}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{barisan}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{pkr}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{dap}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center', color:"black"}}>{pas}</Text>
    </View>
```

I would like to display the boolean value as shown in the image attached in the below.

[image: firestore data]

[app page where data is supposed to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8oT0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display boolean in React Native. If you wanna display boolean in JSX:

```
<Text>{yourBooleanValue.toString()}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This may be a stupid question to ask but is there a way to store the boolean values in the firestore to string values?